# java mysql wil not write to db

Tags: java, mysql, database, forms

I wrote a program a java app that uses u table and a DB.

When i whant to add values to my db nothing happens.

Here is the code to connect and write to DB

```
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author alexa
 */
public class DatabaseManager {

private static Connection connect = null;

public static Boolean ConnectToDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Setup the connection with the DB
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sdb?user=ShiftPilot&password=bunker");

        return true;

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static ResultSet GetTenLastResult()
{
    return null;
}

public static Boolean SearchProblem()
{
    if(ConnectToDatabase()) // if connection ok and saved
    {


    }
    else
        {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}    
public static Boolean SaveMeasuring(String date, String name, String size, String no_production, String grid, String adjust_grid, String adjust_grid2, 
        String thikness, String link_plans_tiles ,String visual_control_white_lines, String visual_control_waves, String adjust_link, String lenght_above,
        String lenght_below, String with_left, String with_right, String angularity_left, String angularity_right, String adjust_measuring, String date_print, 
        String measuring_mousse_s3, String measuring_mousse_s7, String adjust_mousse, String plank_asside_tracking, String cut1_6, String cut2_5, String cut3_8,
        String cut4_7, String cut1_2, String cut3_4, String cut5_6, String cut7_8, String bevel_1, String bevel_3, String bevel_5, String bevel_7)
{
    // save strings to database
    if(ConnectToDatabase()) // if connection ok and savd
    {
        // create a Statement from the connection

        try
        {
        // insert the data

            PreparedStatement  statement;
            statement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO measuring (date, name, size, no_production, grid, adjust_raster, adjust_raster2, thinkness, link_plans_tiles, visual_control_white_lines, visual_control_waves, adjust_link, lenght_above, lenght_below, with_left, with_right, angularity_left, angularity_right, adjust_measuring, date_print, measuring_mousse_s3, measuring_mousse_s7, adjust_mousse, plank_asside_tracking, cut1_6, cut2_5, cut3_8, cut4_7, cut1_2, cut3_4, cut5_6, cut7_8, bevel_1, bevel_3, bevel_5, bevel_7) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, date);
            statement.setString(2, name);
            statement.setString(3, size);
            statement.setString(4, no_production);
            statement.setString(5, grid);
            statement.setString(6, adjust_grid);
            statement.setString(7, adjust_grid2);
            statement.setString(8, thikness);
            statement.setString(9, link_plans_tiles);
            statement.setString(10, visual_control_white_lines);
            statement.setString(11, visual_control_waves);
            statement.setString(12, adjust_link);
            statement.setString(13, lenght_above);
            statement.setString(14, lenght_below);
            statement.setString(15, with_left);
            statement.setString(16, with_right);
            statement.setString(17, angularity_left);
            statement.setString(18, angularity_right);
            statement.setString(19, adjust_measuring);
            statement.setString(20, date_print);
            statement.setString(21, measuring_mousse_s3);
            statement.setString(22, measuring_mousse_s7);
            statement.setString(23, adjust_mousse);
            statement.setString(24, plank_asside_tracking);
            statement.setString(25, cut1_6);
            statement.setString(26, cut2_5);
            statement.setString(27, cut3_8);
            statement.setString(28, cut4_7);
            statement.setString(29, cut1_2);
            statement.setString(30, cut3_4);
            statement.setString(31, cut5_6);
            statement.setString(32, cut7_8);
            statement.setString(33, bevel_1);
            statement.setString(34, bevel_3);
            statement.setString(35, bevel_5);
            statement.setString(36, bevel_7);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is the code that the jbutton uses to send data to DB.

```
private void jButtonAddMeasuring1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    String adr1 = (jComboBoxAdjustGrid1.getSelectedItem().toString() + ": " + jTextFieldAdjustGrid1);
    String adr2 = (jComboBoxAdjustGrid2.getSelectedItem().toString() + ": " + jTextFieldAdjustGrid2);
    if (DatabaseManager.SaveMeasuring(jLabelClock1.getText(), jComboBoxName1.getSelectedItem().toString(),jComboBoxType.getSelectedItem().toString(), noP,
            jComboBoxGrid.getSelectedItem().toString(), adr1, adr2, jTextFieldThickness.toString(), jComboBoxTylesGeneral.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            jComboBoxVisualControlLines.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxVisualControlWave.getSelectedItem().toString(), jTextFieldLinkAdjust.toString(),
            jTextFieldLenghtLeft.toString(), jTextFieldLenghtRight.toString(), jTextFieldWithLeft.toString(), jTextFieldWithRight.toString(), jTextFieldAngularityLeft.toString(),
            jTextFieldAngularityRight.toString(), jTextFieldMeasuringAdjust.toString(), jComboBoxDatePrint.getSelectedItem().toString(), jTextFieldMousse1.toString(),
            jTextFieldMousse2.toString(), jTextFieldMousseAdjust.toString(), jComboBoxTracking.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxCutting1.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
            jComboBoxCutting2.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxCutting3.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxCutting4.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            jComboBoxCutting5.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxCutting6.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxCutting7.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            jComboBoxCutting8.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxBevel1.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxBevel2.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            jComboBoxBevel3.getSelectedItem().toString(), jComboBoxBevel4.getSelectedItem().toString())){
        ok k=new ok();
        k.setVisible (true);
    }else {
        error o=new error();
        o.setVisible (true);
    };}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Print stack trace when you catch exception. 2. Add appropriate logging. 3. Debug.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Debug = split and conquer : check you connection. If the connection is ok try to  preform a simple execute-update, if that is ok check the output of the code in the button action listener.....

Comment: Especially all this could be because of a `NullPointerException` for any `getSelectedItem().toString()` you call. Your best option is to use the debugger here, as mentionned before.

Also (just an advice but will not help answer your question) you may want to have less parameters for your `SaveMeasuring` method. You could create a class to have objects holding those parameters into fields for example.